# Kivy: Update TextInput after picking value from Spinner or Dropdown

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, python-class

Im trying to create GUI with kivy but can't figure this.Created Popup screen and trying to pick value from dropbox and add this value to my TextInput.

**test.py:**

```py
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
    from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    
    class MyDropDown(DropDown):
        def on_select(self, data):
            print('Selected value:',data)
            #Lets add this data to TextInput ?
            MyTextInput.text = data
            #Lets check is that actual text ?
            print('MyTextInput.text is:',MyTextInput.text)
            #HOW CAN I ADD THIS TEXT TEXTINPUT AFTER THAT?
    
    class MySpinner(Spinner):
        dropdown_cls = ObjectProperty(MyDropDown)
    
    class MyTextInput(TextInput):
        pass
    
    class MyTestPopup(Popup):
        my_popup_spinner = ObjectProperty()
        my_textinput_id = ObjectProperty()
    
    class TestPage(Screen):
        MypagePopup = ObjectProperty()
        def open_my_popup(self, *args):
            #Lets create my popup
            self.MypagePopup = MyTestPopup()
            self.MypagePopup.my_popup_spinner.values = ['Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4','Test']
            self.MypagePopup.open()
    
    class TestPageManager(ScreenManager):
        pass
    
    class test(App):
        def build(self):
           return TestPageManager()
    
    if __name__=='__main__':
        test().run()
```

**test.kv:**

```
<TestPageManager>:
    TestPage:
        name: 'mainpagename'
<MySpinner>:
    text: 'Pick Value'
<MyDropDown>:
    values: ['Test1','Test2','Test3','Test4','Test5']
<MyTextInput>:
<MyTestPopup>:
    my_popup_spinner : my_popup_spinner
    my_textinput_id : my_textinput_id
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Testing Label Area..'
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        MyTextInput:
            id: my_textinput_id
        MySpinner:
            id: my_popup_spinner
        Button:
            text: 'Done'
            on_release:
                print('MyTextInput id is :',my_textinput_id.text)
<TestPage>:
    Button:
        text: 'Open Popup'
        on_release: root.open_my_popup()
```

As you can see I created like that GUI.

But can't update TextInput after pick from spinner.How can i update this textinput after pick value from dropbox.I can't figure it out.I think i correctly describe my problem. Thanks for reading and answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kv = "Spinner:

```
        on_text:

              my_textinput_id.text = my_popup_spinner.text"
```

did this in my kv string for Builder.load_string(kv)and it works for me
you can try and implement it in you code example and see if it works.

set the id.text of the textinput = to my spinner id.text in the on_text: event of the Spinner

Comment: Thanks for answering mate. Actually i was using on_text function for Reset my Spinner's text after pick from dropdown. So now if i edit my kivy file like that :
on_text:
        MyTextInputid.text = MySpinnerid.text
        MySpinnerid.text = 'Pick from DropDown'
its failing and returning my spinner's and textinput's text to "Pick from DropDown". Is there any way fix that too ? I don't want mytextinput's text change after change spinner's text..

Comment: Hmm i changed spinnertext with that way: In MySpinner class i created function which has Clock.schedule_once(self.reset_spinners_text).